# iOS UITaprecognizer not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a tap recognizer to a UILabel programmatically. It is not working... I have searched and tried a millions things of stackoverflow, but I can't get it to work...

Here is my current code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(more:)];
[self.moreLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.moreLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 

- (void)more:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"HIT?"); 
}
```

It will work if I add it to the top view but I don't want that ;) Any help is appreciated.

---

Solved using  @Savitha comment:

Summary of answer: "The view I was trying to touch wasn't under another view so either using bringToFront or setting it correctly in IB was the answere."

Comment: Bring moreLabel to front. [self.view bringViewToFront:self.moreLabel];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring moreLabel to front.

```
[self.view bringViewToFront:self.moreLabel];
```